# Reducing spacing between the text and the header

Tags: spacing, vertical-spacing, awesome-cv

I am using an `AwesomeCV` template from Overleaf and want to reduce the spacing between the headings.

In this image, the spacing between the text and the next heading `Skills` is too much and would want to reduce it.

[image]

Following is how I enclose my `Projects` section which is right above `Skills`

```
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
    % project heading etc...
    {
      \begin{cvitems} 
        \item { line 1 }
        \item { line 2 }
        \item {....utility HQ}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
\end{cventries}
```

And the following is how I enclose my `Skills` section

```
\cvsection{Skills}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{cvskills}

  \cvskill
  % stuff ....

\end{cvskills}
```

Answer (score 0):

The space before a section title is controlled by `\acvSectionTopSkip`.
The space after by `\acvSectionContentTopSkip`

You will get [image: a]

by using in the preamble

```
\renewcommand{\acvSectionTopSkip}{-2mm} % reduce the default space
\renewcommand{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}{1.5mm}
```

This is the file `projects.tex` used as example.

```
\cvsection{Projects}
    
\begin{cventries}
    \cventry
    {Software develoment} % Skills
    {Planning \& managment} % Category
    {HQ} % Location
    {Mar. 2020 - Aug. 2021} % Date
    {
        \begin{cvitems}
            \item {Data manipulation} 
            \item {Formal SQL} 
            \item {utility HQ}
        \end{cvitems}
    }
\end{cventries}
```